# Using a filter function with two conditions and one of them is is.na

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, na

Say I have a dataset like this:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6)
number <- c(1, 4, 7, 4, NA, 4)
dat <- data.frame(id, number)
```

I.e.,

```
    id  number
1   1   1
2   2   4 
3   3   7
4   4   4
5   5   NA
6   6   4
```

Using the filter function from dplyr, I can subset just the rows with numbers greater than 3:

```
dat.new <- filter(dat, number > 3)

   id   number
1   2   4
2   3   7
3   4   4
4   6   4
```

And I can also subset the rows with a missing number:

```
dat.new <- filter(dat, is.na(number))

   id   number
1   5   NA
```

But when I try to include rows with numbers NA and greater than 3, it doesn't work.

```
dat.new <- filter(dat, is.na(number) || number > 3)

    id   number
No data available in table
```

What's going on?

Comment: Replace || by |, and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the || operator.  | (single) is the or comparison.  See https://www.r-bloggers.com/logical-operators-in-r/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat.new <- filter(dat, is.na(number) | number > 3)
```